# where i use addDynamicPermissionsPolicy in ASp.net Core2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-roles

I implemented policy in Asp.net. for dynamic role. I do not know where write function with name 'AddDynamicPermissionsPolicy'. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

in startup.cs file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("name1",  policy => policy.....);
    });
}
```

More info: [Custom policy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies)